# How can I solve coupled ODEs including a function as a variable of ODES by odeint?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, odeint

I'm trying to solve 4 coupled ODEs.
I used odeint to solve them, but I can't find the exact method for ODEs including a function as a variable of ODEs. The function is elastance(t) here. The code that I made is as follows:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def elastance(t):
    t = np.array(t)
    Senzaki_table_4=np.array([[28.38975, np.pi/2],[37.58583, .08367674],[21.02345, -1.486758], [7.665592, 2.865675], [4.809436, .1677238], [4.181973, 4.630239], [1.940692, 3.088379], [.5870049, -.3053668], [1.181256, 4.410703], [.84039, 3.181538], [.02259011, 1.242886], [.3071458, 4.156753], [.3226207, 2.946186]])

    hrt_rate = 95
    E_es = 2
    period = 60/hrt_rate
    t_sin = t/period*2*np.pi
    E1 = 1e-2*np.ones(t.shape)[:,None]@Senzaki_table_4[:,0].transpose()[None,:]
    E2 = np.sin(t_sin[:,None] @ np.arange(0,13)[None,:] + np.ones(t.shape)[:,None] @ Senzaki_table_4[:,1][None,:])
    
    #E00 = E1*E2
    E = E_es * np.sum(E1 * E2, 1)

    return E

def opencircuit(x, t):
    # constants
    pressure_conversion = 1333.2237
    L_la = 0.00005
    v_lv0 = 2
    v_d0 = 205+370+401
    R_c = 90/pressure_conversion
    R_d = 1200/pressure_conversion
    C_d = 8e-4*pressure_conversion
    p_la = 12
    initial_v_lv = 128.35607011204
    initial_v_d = 1053.96962417265
    L_la=0.00005
    L_lv=0.000416

    initial_t = 0
    num_cycles = 2.75
    hrt_rate = 95
    final_t = 60 / hrt_rate * num_cycles

    # assgin each ODE to a vector element
    Q_m = x[0]; v_lv = x[1]; Q_a = x[2]; v_d = x[3]

    # define each ODE
    dQ_m_dt = (p_la - elastance([t])*(v_lv- v_lv0))/L_la
    dv_lv_dt = Q_m - Q_a
    dQ_a_dt = 1/L_lv*(elastance([t])*(v_lv-v_lv0) - R_c*Q_a - (v_d-v_d0)/C_d)
    dv_d_dt  = Q_a - (v_d-v_d0)/R_d/C_d

    return [dQ_m_dt, dv_lv_dt, dQ_a_dt, dv_d_dt]

# initial conditions
x0 = [0, 2, 0, 205+370+401]

# test the defined odes
# print(opencircuit(x=x0, t=0))

# declare a time vector (time window)
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1001)
x = odeint(opencircuit, x0, t)

Q_m = x[:, 0]
v_lv = x[:, 1]
Q_a = x[:, 2]
v_d = x[:, 3]

# plot the results
plt.plot(t, elastance(t))
plt.plot(t, Q_m); plt.plot(t, v_lv)
plt.plot(t, Q_a); plt.plot(t, v_d)
plt.show()
```

When I plot elastance(t), it works well.
The first one is the graph which I plotted and the second one is the solution.
[image]
[image]
I think there is no problem with elastance(t).

4 ODEs should be plotted as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB0ii.png)
However, they are plotted like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVcRN.png)
I don't care whether the graphs are displayed at once or separated.

Is there any idea for elastance(t) to work well in 4 coupled ODEs?
I found some clips teaching how to solve coupled ODEs with variables,
but I don't think function elastance(t) can work as if it is a variable.

I don't mind if it's a small part, so please advise.
I'm sorry if my English was not good.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I can see nothing that is fundamentally wrong, the code runs through and produces a plot. Is that plot visibly wrong? Is there some reference what it should look like?

Comment: I edited my question! The plot is totally wrong I think. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: This sounds like a matplotlib question.  Take a look at the [`maplotlib gallery of examples`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html).  You'll see several examples where multiple axes are included in the same figure.

Comment: That you get oscillations instead of a few monotonous segments may hint at a sign error. Please check if all the differences are in the right direction. // The question is on the border of being off-topic as it is more about the mathematical content / simulation results, not about problems in getting numerical results at all.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Thank you for your advice! I’ve seen some examples there. However, in my case, the graphs don’t have to be in the same figure. I just wanna plot ODEs exactly same with the solution. I think it is a scipy problem maybe.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks a lot. 1. It seems reasonable to say that vibration will be a hint. I will check if there are any errors. 2. That’s a good point. I’ve already got results, but the contents are wrong. I’d better search for mathematical / simulation contents.

Comment: Then the place is math.SE (math.stackexchange.com) or scicomp.SE

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! I’ll move the question to math.SE and scicomp.SE :)